# Installing MoviePy for Python 3.2 with pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, moviepy

I am trying to install the Python module MoviePy onto my Raspberry Pi for use with Python 3.2.3 which came ready installed with the OS.  I have tried every command line command that I can find and lots of possible permutations of certain words.

Following are the download instructions.
https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/install.html

After much effort, I eventually managed to download pip and installed moviepy, but it was the Python 2.7 version. 
I found a separate thing called pip3 and installed it using:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip --fix-missing
```

It appeared to be successful.

Eventually I found a command that should work with Python 3.2:
pip-3.2 install moviepy
But it gave the error:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement moviepy
No distributions at all found for moviepy
Storing complete log in /home/Pi/.pip/pip.log
```

What do I do?
I have no knowledge of CLI at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
sudo pip install ez_setup

sudo pip install moviepy
```

If it says like pip not found type

```
sudo apt-get install python
```

Python 3 is a little harder to setup so doing that command will give you 2.7
But there syntax is basicly the same.

Comment: Are you basically saying "do this command" but then you are saying it won't actually work because it is for Python 2.7? I have no experience with these commands so I can't adjust the syntax...

Comment: Have just put it into the Pi and it was the 'ez_setup' that hadn't been installed. I have been over the commands so many times in weird orders that I hadn't done it when it needed to be done. However, it needed to say "sudo pip-3.2 install moviepy" to work for my version of Python. Thanks

Comment: nice job figuring that out